# Add/Edit list item at parent from child component form

Tags: vue.js

I am developing a recipe app. At my CreateRecipe component, I have child component to add ingredients to the recipe or edit existing ingredients. Ill start by showing the code and what i want to achieve and then the problem

**Parent component:**

```
 <template>
    ...
        <v-dialog v-model="AddIgredientsDialog" max-width="800px">
           <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
               <v-btn color="secondary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                   Add addIngredients
               </v-btn>
           </template>
            <AddItemsForm
                @addIngredient="SaveNewIgredient"
                :newIngredientsItem="editedIgredient"
                />
      </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import AddItemsForm from "./AddItemsForm"; //Child Component

data: () => ({
     AddIgredientsDialog:false,
     article: {
      headline: "",
      img: "",
      content: "",
      subHeader: "",
      description: "",

      igredients: [], //List to add/edit item at AddItemsForm child component
      preperation: []
    },
    editedIgredient: { //Item to use for editing or adding new item to article.igredients
      title: "",
      subIgredients: []
    },
    defaultItem: { //Item used for resetting editedIgredient item
      title: "",
      subIgredients: []
    },
    editedIndex: -1, helper variable for knowing whether i need to add new item or edit exiting item
   
}),
methods:{
        editIngredients(item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.article.igredients.indexOf(item);
      this.editedIgredient = Object.assign({}, item);
      this.AddIgredientsDialog = true;
    },
    SaveNewIgredient(newItem) { //Triggered on @click of save button at child component New item is the 
                                //item passed  from children
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        this.editedIgredient = Object.assign({}, newItem);
        Object.assign(
          this.article.igredients[this.editedIndex],
          this.editedIgredient
        );
      } else {
        this.article.igredients.push(this.editedIgredient);
      }
      this.AddIgredientsDialog = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedIgredient = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      });
    },
}

</script>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="headline">Add Ingredients</span>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-text-field v-model="newIngredientsItem.title" placeholder="כותרת">
      </v-text-field>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col sm="11">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="newIgredient"
            placeholder="New Igredient"
            @keyup.enter="addNewIgredient"
          >
          </v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col sm="1">
          <v-btn icon @click="addNewIgredient">
            <v-icon>
              mdi-plus
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="mt-0 pt-0" cols="12">
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-card flat tile>
                <template
                  v-for="(item, index) in newIngredientsItem.subIgredients"
                >
                  <v-list-item :key="index" class="mr-0 pr-0">
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title>
                        <v-edit-dialog @click.native.stop>
                          {{ item }}
                          <v-text-field
                            slot="input"
                            v-model="newIngredientsItem.subIgredients[index]"
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-edit-dialog>
                      </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-action>
                      <v-btn icon @click="removeIgredient(index)">
                        <v-icon small>
                          mdi-delete
                        </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                  </v-list-item>
                  <v-divider
                    v-if="index + 1 < newIngredientsItem.subIgredients.length"
                    :key="item + index"
                  ></v-divider>
                </template>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="AddIngredients">
        Save
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    newIngredientsItem: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          title: "",
          subIgredients: [ ]
        };
      }
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    newIgredient: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    addNewIgredient() {
      this.newIngredientsItem.subIgredients.push(this.newIgredient);
      this.newIgredient = "";
    },
    AddIngredients() {
      this.$emit("addIngredient", this.newIngredientsItem);
    },
    removeIgredient(index) {
      this.newIngredientsItem.subIgredients.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**My Problem:**

At the moment im only trying to use the `SaveNewIgredient()` method.
After 1st time of adding item the item is added as it should and the parent `defaultItem` state  remain as is which is good:

```
 defaultItem: {
      title: "",
      subIgredients: []
    },
```

After adding a second item the `defaultItem` changes and takes the `editedItem` properties.
For example if i add at the second time

```
{
    title:'Test 1',
    subIgredients: [
        'Test 1 - 1',
        'Test 1 - 2', 
        'Test 1 - 3', 
    ]    
}
```

That is what the defaultItem will be and then this assignment causes a bug

```
this.editedIgredient = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
```

because editedItem should be:

```
{
    title: "",
    subIgredients: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem. To do this I modified and in some places simplified your code to keep only what was close to the SaveNewIgredient() function. So here is my code.

Parent Component (for me App.vue):

```
<template>
  <AddItemsForm @addIngredient="SaveNewIgredient" />
</template>

<script>
import AddItemsForm from "./AddItemsForm"; //Child Component

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { AddItemsForm },
  data() {
    return {
      article: {
       igredients: [], //List to add/edit item at AddItemsForm child component
      },
      editedIgredient: {
        //Item to use for editing or adding new item to article.igredients
        title: "",
        subIgredients: [],
      },
      defaultItem: {
        //Item used for resetting editedIgredient item
        title: "",
        subIgredients: [],
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    SaveNewIgredient(newItem) {
      console.log("Received: ", newItem);

      this.editedIgredient = newItem;
      this.article.igredients.push({ ...this.editedIgredient });
      console.log("defaultClear: ", this.defaultItem);
      console.log("infoItem: ", this.editedIgredient);

      this.editedIgredient = this.defaultItem;

      console.log("defaultClear: ", this.defaultItem);
      console.log("editedWillClear: ", this.editedIgredient);
      console.log("listFinal: ", this.article.igredients);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Child Component (for me AddItemsForm.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="newIgredient" placeholder="New Igredient" />
    <button @click="addNewIgredient">ADD</button>
    <div>
      <button color="primary" @click="AddIngredients">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    IngredientsItem: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          title: "",
          subIgredients: [],
        };
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newIgredient: "",
      title: "TEST",
      titleNbr: 0,
      resetIgredient: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    newIngredientsItem() {
      return this.IngredientsItem;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addNewIgredient() {
      if (this.resetIgredient === true) {
        this.newIngredientsItem.subIgredients = [];
      }
      this.newIngredientsItem.subIgredients.push(this.newIgredient);
      this.newIgredient = "";
      this.resetIgredient = false;
      console.log("ADD: ", this.newIngredientsItem.subIgredients);
    },
    AddIngredients() {
      this.newIngredientsItem.title = this.title + this.titleNbr;
      this.titleNbr++;
      console.log("EMIT: ", this.newIngredientsItem);
      this.$emit("addIngredient", this.newIngredientsItem);
      this.resetIgredient = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, That solved the adding functionality, But there are 2 issues that solutions makes, that caused because the object is not passed as prop to the child. 1 is that after adding 1st ingredients object and then opening the dialog again, the data is populated with last item data. 2 is that it does not answer the editing requirement that the child component should support. The same child component should also be able to edit items in the parent list. My solution was to change the assignment to this.editedIgredient = {
        title: "",
        subIgredients: []
      };

Comment: I have just edited my code, so that the ingredient is a child's PROPS. Then to avoid any mutating errors, I use a small function in COMPUTED to give me access to the props.
And what are you talking about when you say reopen the dialog?Because I know that when I worked on this code, when I saved an "object" (sending this.newIngredientsItem to the parent) it was applied to all the objects already existing in the parent's list.  To solve this I used:
this.article.igredients.push({ ...this.editedIgredient });   important was this '...'

Comment: I meant by reopen the dialog that if say i want to add another item to the parent igredients list, The data at the child component is populated with the last item added, and there is need to delete it and then start entering the new data. Its still works, But just bad UX, You sure you updated your code when you edited? I dont see for some reason the new code. Thanks for the idea of having COMPUTED  function to access the prop data, I knew i was doing something bad there and it didn`t came up to mind

Comment: ok, So I understand correctly and with my code I think I solve your problem with the DATA 'resetIgredient' because with this I delete the 'subIgredients' after an emit with AddIngredients(). And yes under my answer I can see from left to right: share, edit, delete, flag, big space and 'edited XX mins ago' currently for me it's 56min and it's my update for you